# How to wrap a div round an image, responsive for larger and smaller PC screen size

Tags: html, css

I am trying to recreate a design gotten from a UX Designer,

[image: Expected Design]

the design is was created for a screen size of 1440px, which is expected to be responsive across  992px, after much work trying to wrap my div around the image, this is what I get

[image]

The problem here is, is there a standard way to wrap div around the image for a perfect fit...
Below is my sample code

HTML

```
<div class="goal">
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12" style="padding: 0">
    <img src="assets/images/image4.png">
</div>
<div class="goal-txt col-md-8 col-xs-12">
    <h2>Vivamus quis</h2>
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ut.</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque maximus imperdiet ultrices. Proin at sagittis dolor. Nam nec ligula mi. Donec tortor purus, aliquet quis rutrum in, lobortis ut justo. Sed ultricies mauris a dignissim finibus. Curabitur feugiat, lorem eget congue suscipit, felis massa facilisis turpis, vel euismod dui turpis in odio. Aliquam ultricies pretium diam, sed ultrices odio posuere vitae. Donec commodo velit vitae nunc interdum, vitae ultrices dolor sagittis. Praesent tincidunt nibh at nisl cursus, eget commodo turpis dapibus. Fusce ac suscipit leo, at euismod velit. Curabitur consequat bibendum justo nec ultricies. Cras nec lacus eu dolor vehicula mattis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Etiam libero urna, tempor non.</li>
        <li>Sed vitae molestie ligula. Donec.</li>
        <li>Etiam libero urna, tempor non.</li>
        <li>Sed vitae molestie ligula. Donec.</li>
        <li>Etiam libero urna, tempor non.</li>
        <li>Sed vitae molestie ligula. Donec.</li>
    </ul>
</div> </div>
```

CSS

```
.goal-txt {
    background: #F4F7FC;
    padding: 32px 78px 86px 78px;
 }
```

Comment: give that div `display: inline-block`

Comment: which div in particular?

Comment: The one above the image, here with `col*` . Also you are missing a closing `</div>`

Comment: To be able to answer _" is there a standard way to wrap div around the image for a perfect fit "_ you need to explain what that actually means. If an image has a landscape ratio, and the `div` has portrait, it either gets cut off at left/right, or leave uncovered area at top/bottom (if image is centered that of course).

Comment: by asking "_is there a standard way to wrap div around the image for a perfect fit?_" I meant I could actually adjust the padding to fit the image with the DIV but once the screen size changes it affects either the div or the image

Comment: Where does the class `col-md-8 col-xs-12` come from? Do you use bootstrap? If yes, you can use bootstrap's column system. If not, you could use `display:flex` to align items next to each other and make them all the same height.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you have an image of 713px height and your text content is less height. I would say give your goal-txt of the same height as your image. So that makes:

```
.goal-txt {
    max-height: 713px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
 }
```